# Access properties file embedded in EAR/lib jar from WAR module

Tags: jakarta-ee, classloader, wildfly-10

I have a straight forward J2EE app packaged as an EAR and deployed to Wildfly 10.1.0 running on RHEL. The EAR contains an EJB module, a WAR module, and a commons library module (Commons-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) that resides in the /lib folder of the EAR along with other dependencies.  In the root of Commons-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar I have a properties file (util.properties), that is read by a utility/helper class (i.e., cc.iapps.sprd.commons.Utility) that's packaged in the same jar. 
  The WAR module uses the Utility class, but when it initializes the class, the properties file is failing to load with the following error:

**The properties file was not found.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content/SpreadServices-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/Commons-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/util.properties (No such file or directory)**

The Utility class is indeed loaded, so I know the Commons-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is in the WAR's classpath. Also, I've verified that the properties file is located at the root of the jar file and that the jar file is in the /lib folder of the EAR.

The code I use to load the properties file is as follows:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("util.properties").getFile());
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream(file));
```

What's odd is that the app works fine when deployed from Eclipse to Wildfly 10.1 locally on my development machine.  I suspect it's because the local version is deployed as an exploded EAR referencing my development file structure.

Answer (score 2):

You should not in general be trying to read class-loader resources as `java.io.File` objects. They do not exist in the file system unless you happen to perform on exploded deployment.

The solution that you provide can be collapsed down to:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/util.properties"));
```

or more properly:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
try (InputStream utilsInput = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/util.properties")) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(utilsInput);
    ...
}
```

for proper resource management.

Comment: Thanks Steve, you are correct.  That is in fact a change I made along with the path fix.  Using the file system method was the result of my JUnit tests being executed on the class prior to it being packaged in the jar.    I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the resource name has to be prefixed with '/', so changing the code to the following resolved it:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("/util.properties").getFile());
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(file));
```